# Is there a way to Button click show/hide functional component in React native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Is there a way to show and hide component on button click in react native functional component? I have a function in which two custom buttons. I want to show view if one button selected and if second button select then first button view hide and showing second button view. How can i achieve this?
Here is my function code..

```
     const SupportScreen = ({ props, navigation }) => {
          const lists = [
            {id: 1, title: 'Pending Tickets'},
            {id: 2, title: 'Resolved Tickets'},
          ];
          const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
        
     
    
     <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10}}>
          {lists.map(list => (
            <CustomButton
              key={list.id}
              customclick={() => {
                handleColor(list);
              }}
              title={list.title}
              style={{
                backgroundColor:
                  list.id === selected
                    ? Constants.Colors.PRIMARY
                    : Constants.Colors.WALLTE_TXT_GRAY_COLOR,
                width: 180,
                elevation: 3,
              }}
              
              tColor={Constants.Colors.WHITE}
            
              tfz={12}></CustomButton>
            
            
          ))}
          
        </View>
        
           
        
          const handleColor = row => {
            setSelected(row.id);
        
          };
  </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/view-rendering)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

const lists = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Pending Tickets' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Resolved Tickets' },
];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(lists[0].id);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {lists.map((list) => (
        <Button
          key={list.id}
          title={list.title}
          onPress={() => setSelected(list.id)} // Set Selected to this id
          color={list.id === selected ? 'dodgerblue' : 'grey'} // Render depending on the id 
          style={{
            width: 180,
            elevation: 3,
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

For Rendering a View based on the ID, you can do something like this

```js
{selected == 1 ? (
  <View>
      <Text>View One Here</Text>
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View>
      <Text>View Two Here</Text>
  </View>
)}
```

Comment: Hay, But i want to render a view on selected button. Your answer is not fulfill on my requirement.

Comment: You can use Pressable instead of Button and render anything

Comment: @Michael Bahl  can you please provide any source or example for this? i am new in react native

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/toggle-one-button-after-another)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const lists = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Pending Tickets 1', color: '#ff0000' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Resolved Tickets 2', color: '#ffff00'  },
    { id: 3, title: 'Resolved Tickets 3', color: '#ff00ff'  },
    { id: 4, title: 'Resolved Tickets 4', color: '#00ffff'  },
    { id: 5, title: 'Resolved Tickets 5', color: '#ccccc'  },
    { id: 6, title: 'Resolved Tickets 6', color: '#00ff00'  },
  ];
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(1);
  const handleColor = () => {
    setSelected((selected % lists.length) + 1);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10 }}>
        {lists
          .filter((item, index) => index === selected - 1)
          .map((list, index) => {
            return (
              <Pressable
                onPress={() => {
                  handleColor();
                }}>
                <Text style={{color: list.color}}>{list.title}</Text>
              </Pressable>
            );
          })
          .filter(Boolean)}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: How to show/hide view on selected button

Comment: Here is another sample https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/toggle-jsx-elements